# Changing icon on dropdown and javascript transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This dropdown icon wont turn smoothly, transitions dont work, when the dropdown opens its sudden, same with when it closes, it doesnt close when you click elsewhere on the screen and stays open.
hopefully someone can help and if there is an answer it helps other people looking to do similar.

Here is my code:
JsFiddle if you find it easier: https://jsfiddle.net/Vorex/tr3196L7/1/

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.cssText === "display: block;") {
  dropdownContent.style.cssText = "display: none;";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.cssText = "display: block;";
  }
  });
}


$(".btn_body").click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-right');
      if ($(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").hasClass("fa-caret-down")) {
          $(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-right');
      }
  });
```

```css
/*===================
    CHAT SIDEBAR
====================*/

.chatbar  {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    font-family: 'Tomorrow', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363b42;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.chatbar h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.chatbar a, .dropdown-btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color: white;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
.chatbar a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
    background-color: #5a626d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

.chatbar img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    float: left;
}

.chatbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Tomorrow', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #363b42;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.btn_body {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="chatbar">
    <h1> Chatbar </h1><br>
  <a href="chat.php" style="color: lightgreen;"> Global Chat </a>
  <a href="#" style="color: orange;"> Messages </a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn btn_body">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what exactly are you trying to achieve?!
it obviously can not work, because you don't have any transitions. you are just replacing a class on every click. there is nothing to animate...

Comment: I want to transition rotate the icon on click so it goes from `fa-fa-right` to `fa-fa-down`

Comment: well then, do a rotation instead of a replacement... you know you can rotate anything? just don’t replace it.

Comment: thats the thing im having trouble with i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comment you need to rotate your object by either applying a JS animation or (probably easier for you) toggle a class, which rotates your object.

Here an example, and you can obviously adapt it to use jQuery... i don't use it, as i don't like it:

```js
const ddButton = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');

ddButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  document.querySelector(".fa.fa-caret-up").classList.toggle("rotate-icon");
});
```

```css
.fa-caret-up {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.fa-caret-up.rotate-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown-btn btn_body">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
```